# Angular development and TFS

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm, tfs, node-modules

I am about to start a new Angular development.

So far, I have been doing it by following Angular documentation - installing node packages and then creating an Angular project.

Now, I want to move development into existing VS solution to have everything under the same hood. We are using TFS for a source control and continuous integration.

Our branch strategy requires that each branch would have a complete solution so it can run independently. Seems to me that checking in the whole Angular project (with node modules - 64 thousands files) into every branch is not the best approach.

So, my question is: is there a way of installing just a minimum of node modules that Angular needs?

I have installed Angular CLI: **npm install @angular/cli**, but still it is about 8000 files. Anyone could share Angular/TFS experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend any `node_modules` going in to your version control.

I would make TFS ignore the `node_modules` and set up a way to just keep them local. NPM should make a [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file for you and a [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) file. This should be included in your version control strategy as it allows to keep track of packages and dependencies without needing the `node_modules`.

This would mean that the `node_modules` you keep locally should be fine and if new packages have been added to the `package.json` you could run `npm i` to get the latest of each package you need. This would save trying to pull `node_modules` up and down through version control.

I cant help more with the TFS side but something like this should help you achieve what you are looking for.

some good information to look at in this [article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8). Little old but think for the most part it stands true.

Comment: Will take a look at the article you are providing. But meanwhile, when you are saying  keep node_modules locally how a development in a particular branch can be done by multiple developers? They all will need these specific packages. Keeping them in TFS makes it simple, but not practical - too many files.

Comment: so when you keep the package.json and package-lock.json in the version control if you install something and that merges, then when someone else pulls it down. All they have to do before starting dev build of angular project they need to run npm i. And this will pick up the newly installed packages and install them locally (update current node_modules)

Comment: I think I understand. I only check in package.json and package-lock.json, right?

Comment: yeah, that way `npm i` will get the `node_modules` all up to date. Hope this helps